# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon')

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am new with android and I am trying to make an application that can analyse the noise level and I found a useful resource unfortunately I am getting the above mentioned error. I have attached all my files hence any clues to fix this would be really appreciated.

This is the manifest file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.prabalgupta.noisealert"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidexample.noisealert.NoiseAlert"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

noisealert.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class NoiseAlert extends Activity {
/* constants */
private static final int POLL_INTERVAL = 300;

/**
 * running state
 **/
private boolean mRunning = false;

/**
 * config state
 **/
private int mThreshold;

private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

/* References to view elements */
private TextView mStatusView;
private SoundLevelView mDisplay;

/* data source */
private SoundMeter mSensor;


/******************
 * Define runnable thread again and again detect noise
 *********/

private Runnable mSleepTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Log.i("Noise", "runnable mSleepTask");

        start();
    }
};

// Create runnable thread to Monitor Voice
private Runnable mPollTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        double amp = mSensor.getAmplitude();
        //Log.i("Noise", "runnable mPollTask");
        updateDisplay("Monitoring Voice...", amp);

        if ((amp > mThreshold)) {
            callForHelp();
            //Log.i("Noise", "==== onCreate ===");

        }

        // Runnable(mPollTask) will again execute after POLL_INTERVAL
        mHandler.postDelayed(mPollTask, POLL_INTERVAL);

    }
};
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

/*********************************************************/

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Defined SoundLevelView in main.xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

    // Used to record voice
    mSensor = new SoundMeter();
    mDisplay = (SoundLevelView) findViewById(R.id.volume);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "NoiseAlert");
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Log.i("Noise", "==== onResume ===");

    initializeApplicationConstants();
    mDisplay.setLevel(0, mThreshold);

    if (!mRunning) {
        mRunning = true;
        start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "NoiseAlert Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.prabalgupta.noisealert/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
    // Log.i("Noise", "==== onStop ===");

    //Stop noise monitoring
    stop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.disconnect();
}

private void start() {
    //Log.i("Noise", "==== start ===");

    mSensor.start();
    if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    //Noise monitoring start
    // Runnable(mPollTask) will execute after POLL_INTERVAL
    mHandler.postDelayed(mPollTask, POLL_INTERVAL);
}

private void stop() {
    Log.i("Noise", "==== Stop Noise Monitoring===");
    if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mSleepTask);
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mPollTask);
    mSensor.stop();
    mDisplay.setLevel(0, 0);
    updateDisplay("stopped...", 0.0);
    mRunning = false;

}


private void initializeApplicationConstants() {
    // Set Noise Threshold
    mThreshold = 8;

}

private void updateDisplay(String status, double signalEMA) {
    mStatusView.setText(status);
    //
    mDisplay.setLevel((int) signalEMA, mThreshold);
}


private void callForHelp() {

    //stop();

    // Show alert when noise thersold crossed
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Noise Thersold Crossed, do here your stuff.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "NoiseAlert Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app deep link URI is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.prabalgupta.noisealert/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}
};
```

SoundLevelView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

class SoundLevelView extends View {
private Drawable mGreen;
private Drawable mRed;
private Paint mBackgroundPaint;

private int mHeight;
private int mWidth;

private int mThreshold = 0;
private int mVol = 0;


public SoundLevelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mGreen  = context.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.greenbar);
    mRed    = context.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.redbar);

    mWidth  = mGreen.getIntrinsicWidth();
    setMinimumWidth(mWidth*10);

    mHeight = mGreen.getIntrinsicHeight();
    setMinimumHeight(mHeight);

    //Used to paint canvas background color
    mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
    mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

}

public void setLevel(int volume, int threshold) {
    if (volume == mVol && threshold == mThreshold) return;
    mVol = volume;
    mThreshold = threshold;

    // invalidate Call onDraw method and draw voice points
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawPaint(mBackgroundPaint);

    for (int i=0; i<= mVol; i++) {
        Drawable bar;
        if (i< mThreshold)
            bar = mGreen;
        else
            bar = mRed;

        bar.setBounds((10-i)*mWidth, 0, (10-i+1)*mWidth, mHeight);
        bar.draw(canvas);
    }
}
}
```

SoundMeter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class SoundMeter {
// This file is used to record voice
static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private double mEMA = 0.0;

public void start() {

    if (mRecorder == null) {

        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mRecorder.start();
        mEMA = 0.0;
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}

public double getAmplitude() {
    if (mRecorder != null)
        return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
    else
        return 0;

}

public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
    double amp = getAmplitude();
    mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
    return mEMA;
}
```

Activity_noise_alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="stopped"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >

        <com.androidexample.noisealert.SoundLevelView
            android:id="@+id/volume"
            android:layout_width="230sp"
            android:layout_height="60sp"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It seems that you miss a file called `icon.png` in your `drawable` folder.

Comment: Please try to post a minimal example - the smallest amount of code needed for us to reproduce your issue. What you have posted is a lot to work through, and will make it harder to answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest file you are trying to set a icon for your application 
through this code `android:icon="@drawable/icon"` .

that means you should have a icon.png img inside `res/drawable` folder.otherwise  put a icon.png img inside drawable folder then your problem will be resolved. there is no mandatory that img file name would be icon.png , it can be any name like ic_launcher.png..... then you need to change your manifest file like this `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

but img will be png format.

Thank You